# Vuetify v-card shadow after resize

Tags: vue.js, styles, vuetify.js, shadow

I'm working on Vuetify app and I have problem with shadow behind v-card. When I click on button, I get small card because I used: class="mx-auto justify-center" max-width="512px".
Problem is that behind this card is black shadow and I need to get rid of it.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsHjS.png)

I hope it is possible to get rid of it. Thanks for replies.

Comment: In the picture you posted, I feel you are using a ``v-dialog``. If it is true, then you can add ``hide-overlay`` to it. Then the ``overlay`` -the so called shadow- will be removed. It would be nice if you can provide us the code you are using.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your help. My problem was that I had page, that page contain Component, that contains dialog and that dialog contain another component which is v-card and I was changing this v-card element with max-width.. I removed that and changed v-dialog with max-width and its working great.